# Изменить значение href JS

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href = 'auth/login.php';" id="btn_login">Вход</button>



<?php

        if(isset($_SESSION['logged_user']))
        { 
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("btn_login").innerHTML = "Выход" </script>';
        
        }
?>
```

Получается если кнопка была нажата, то я меняю её значение.
Как изменить еще и href кнопки?

Comment: А зачем менять?... Юзер зашел - выводите одну кнопку, юзер не залогинился - другую

Comment: @InDevX так не получается. Я вставляю условие в php,но при нажатии ничего не происходит

Comment: [Авторизация на PHP](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=examples&page=068)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  echo isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])
    ? '<button onclick="location.href=&quot;/auth/login.php&quot;" id="btn_login">Вход</button>'
    : '<button onclick="location.href=&quot;/auth/logout.php&quot;" id="btn_login">Вsход</button>';
?>
```